# How to mask the URL with htaccess in zend framework 1.10

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

Hi I Have to create the URL something like "http://www.contract.com/user/profileview/index/MQ==" to "http://www.contract.com/profile/india/MQ==". We have tried the masking with codeignitor and succeeded. But coming to the Zend it is throwing the error "Invalid controller specified (india)".

We have rewrite the htaccess rules to Mask the URL in codeignitor. Same is applied here, but it is not working here. My htaccess code is

```
#php_value magic_quotes_gpc off
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Admin
RewriteRule ^admin(.*)$ public_mvc/admin.php [L]

#RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)(/|)$ user/profileview/index/$2 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)(/|)$ user/profileview/index/$2 [L,NC]

#RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ user/profileview/index/$2 [L,NC,QSA]

# Also Tried Ones. Start

#RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /user/profileview/index/$1 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /user/profileview/index/$2 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /user/profileview/index/$2 [NC]
#RewriteRule ^/profile/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /user/profileview/index/$2 [QSA]

# Also Tried Ones. End

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_mvc/index.php

Rewriterule ^$ /home [r=301,nc]
```

What is the wrong with this? We have tried so many types options. But all went in vain. You can see all those different tries in the code. Please help me this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to use the zend router instead of htaccess ? http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html

Comment: If you use zend router, it gives you that wished result by default.

Answer (score 0):

"http://www.contract.com/profile/india/MQ=="

above url can be rewriter in htaccess

method 1;
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ redirectedUrl.php [NC,L]

redirectedUrl.php  as page, it should be placed in the root directory, it cant shows an error, regards changing the url in htaccess!!!

method 2;
handling on bootstapper.php for redirect into some controller with another action for using

Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex

Comment: Like you said in method one, If I use the redirectUrl.php in the root directory and point that page from htaccess will redirect the page to the URL. I want my page to be redirected to the page but the URL in the Browser should look like the "<http://www.contract.com/profile/india/MQ==>".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Support. I have achieved the goal in some other way. We have changed the ZEND routing according to our needs. So we have Auth file(which is called in every request). This file is called in all the requests. So what I did is I checked the URL and if the URL contains the module name as 'Profile' then I have set the Module, Controller and Action name using the "setModuleName", "setControllerName", "setActionName", etc..

```
$ModuleName = $request->getModuleName();
$ControllderName = $request->getControllerName();
$ActionName = $request->getActionName();

/*
  This condition is added to mask the URL. This is added by Ghanta Kiran on 27-Dec-2013. Start
  Example : (From) http://www.contractskills.com/profile/india/username/id  ==> (To) http://www.contractskills.com/user/profileview/index/id
*/
if($ModuleName == 'profile')
{
 $paramId = $request->getParam('id'); // This is to get the User Id from the URL, to fetch the user profile details.
 $request->setModuleName('user');
 $request->setControllerName('profileview');
 $request->setActionName('index');
 $request->setParam('id',$paramId);         
}
```

So what it will do is, If the URL Contains the 'Profile' in it, it will set the Module, Controller, Actions explicitly. I have done so many changes to the .htaccess, but ultimately all those efforts went wild.